# Recommend iPhone library for image gallery?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

I would love to use a UIImagePickerController to browse and view images from my app's bundle.  However this functionality doesn't seem to exist.  Is there a library that replicates the functionality of the photo browser, but can use a list of images from the app bundle?

Answer (score 6):

When GitHub is back online, check the [Three20](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master) repository of joehewitt with some awesome iPhone UI stuff. I believe it is the TTThumbsViewController you may want to take a look at.

Comment: Hey thanks, cool stuff and exactly what I needed!  Hopefully GitHub comes back soon.. They have been getting slower and slower lately.  I hope they're not having too major an issue!